# Size of conformal factor under uniformisation

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, curvature

Consider closed orientable surfaces whose metrics are hyperbolic (i.e., $K=-1$) except in a region which is a hemisphere of a unit sphere attached to the hyperbolic region along a closed geodesic (of length $2\pi$).  By uniformisation, such a metric is conformally equivalent to a hyperbolic metric, with a suitable conformal factor $f$, where $f$ is a global function on the surface.  I am interested in the following two questions concerning the "size" of such functions $f$ as the genus $g$ tends to infinity.

1. Is $f$ necessarily bounded above and below uniformly in $g$?
2. If the answer to part 1 is affirmative, I have a follow-up question.  Suppose the attaching geodesic is allowed to grow slowly as a function of the genus, say as $\log g$ (with the corresponding adjustment for the size of the hemisphere).  Are there still uniform estimates for the size of $f$ as a function of $g$?